# Image url for messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have active storage installed, and I am using it for user avatar, which uploads fine. I have a message model, where two users can message each other kind of like direct messages on social media, and I want to show the avatar on each user's message. I can't get the picture to show. It raises an error. I believe my code is wrong.

My code is in a partial:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= image_tag(@avatar(message.user)) %>
    <strong><%= message.user.fullname %></strong>
    <span class="pull-right"><%= message.message_time %></span>
    <br/>
    <div class="row-space-2">
      <%= message.context %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is "king of like direct messages"? I know "the king of burgers", but probably that's not it.

Comment: sorry typo lol fixed it

Comment: Try to debug if `@avatar(message.user)` is returning image url. If not you are using it wrong.

Comment: message.user.avatar_url should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the correct URL or path for the attachment with:

```
url_for(message.user.avatar)
path_for(message.user.avatar)
```

Don't use `image_tag` here. It's an assets helper that is meant to serve images through the assets pipeline - which mean basically static images that are part of the design of the app.

Instead just use plain HTML:

```
<img src="<%= path_for(message.user.avatar) %>">
```

Or the [plain tag helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag):

```
<%= tag.img src: path_for(message.user.avatar) %>
```